# I can't link external css into HTML

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[Here is the error now showing in browser console, anyone please explain what is this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVMqq.jpg)this is a screenshot of html file

[image]

I'm building a web page using Bootstrap, I have added Bootstrap CSS and my CSS into "head" tag. Here is the code-

```
 <head>


     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!--Bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>
        first web page using bootstrap
      </title>
<!-- Font awesome for brand name-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

      <!--Our CSS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style.css" >

  </head>
```

Here is what I have added into my CSS-

```
.mybanner{

  background-color: rgb(12, 8, 5);
  text-align: center;
}


.mybg{

  background-color: rgb(161, 86, 86);
}

.other{
  width: 30px;
 height: 30px;

}
```

Here is the whole code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>


     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!--Bootstrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>
        first web page using bootstrap
      </title>
<!-- Font awesome for brand name-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

      <!--Our CSS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style.css" >

  </head> 
<body>

  <!-- Nav bar-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg mybg" style="background-color: #3be79f;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: rgb(141, 7, 7); font-size: 25px; font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;"> Stiffy </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Categories
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Beauty</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Health</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lifestyle</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Your Cart</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!--slideshow starts-->


    <div class="fluid-container">

      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="../Image\unsplash.jpg"  alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Photography</h3>
              <p>It is always so much fun!</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="../Image\zombie-945622.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Ghost</h3>
              <p>Thank you, Mr. Demon</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="img-1" src="../Image\zombie-979358.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%; height: 60%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3> Oops.</h3>
              <p>Ghosts are best.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>


     <!--slideshow ends-->

<!-- Banner starts-->
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="row" class="mybanner" style= "background-color: #3be79f;
  text-align: center;"
  >
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"  >

      24*7 Services

     </div>


  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"  >

    Cheaper in price

  </div>


<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"  >

  Deliver ASAP

</div>

</div>

</div>

<!-- Banner ends-->

<!-- other stuff-->
<div class="other">
  <img src="../Image\bride.jpg">
</div>


<!-- JQuery,JS, BOOTSTRAP JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have added class properly, don't know why it's not working. Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: why is there a `\\` in the href ?

Comment: what doesn't work? your css? have you try to look at the browser dev console to see if there is some errors?

Comment: According to your screenshot, the HTML document is in a folder named `HTML`. The `CSS` folder is not _inside_ of that, but located _parallel_ to it in the same parent folder - so you need to go one folder level up first, to get “out” of the HTML folder.

Comment: This type of question has gone rampant on SO lately. I can only assume no attempt was made to search for an answer on SO or the internet in general where it is also one of the most asked questions (which usually has the same solution). Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=can%27t+link+external+css

Comment: @Rob, I checked all of them, none of them able to solve my problem.Even after so many answers here, my problem ain't solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the folder of html, you should use .. to go out of the folder and then tell to what folder to ender /CSS/ and then to select the file style.css
Use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" />
```

Comment: Note that the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Please swap this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style.css" >
```

To this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" >
```

EDIT: As @renaldo-balaj explains you're in a HTML folder so to access the CSS folder you would need to use `../` to hop up one level in your folder directory then go into CSS then grab styles.css

Also to add you used the wrong `\`

EDIT 29/11:

Ok I have removed the HTML not needed to show that this works properly.. You must be implementing the solution wrong. You have 2 answers that are correct and this post should be closed due to lack of context and over duplciation of 100 other posts around this relative path issues.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>


     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <title>
        first web page using bootstrap
      </title>

      <!--Our CSS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css" >
  </head> 
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Folder Structure:

```
Project
│ 
│   
├───CSS
│       style.css
│       
└───HTML
        index.html
```

So here I will try explain further your issue.

`\` backslashes are not used in filepaths, as per @birspider's answer which shows the HTML validator state that.

You have your index.html in a HTML folder which isn't normal for a static website so becuase of this unless your CSS file is in the same directory to that HTML file then you need to use the `../` to hop up out of the HTML folder, then `/CSS` to go into your CSS folder and then `/style.css` to grab the style.css file and serve it.

Again your DevTools console would of advised you of where it was trying to look and you should be able to debug from there.

Please close this post and accept a answer.

Image from my browser showing that background-color: black; worked from the style.css file: https://ibb.co/ys1Kvvt

Comment: Actually, I copied relative path of that css file from VS Code explorer window and pasted. However, now I edited it still not working.

Comment: Can you please check your console for any errors? As the client would make a request and if it can't get the file due to a issue it will list that issue in the devtools console. 

What OS you running? As I believe Mac OS using the \ backslashes. 

Can you please update your post with the most recent filepath used and your most recent folder structure to your project. Also any conosole errors you have got.

Comment: I have updated my answer, to show my solution does work..?

Comment: First of all thank you for this,  I'm using Windows 10. I checked console and found an error, please check question now I've uploaded a screenshot. Still I don't know what's the error cause I'm Newbie. As for as backslash \ is concerned, i think that doesn't matter either you use / or \ cause I tried both in a `img` tag, and as a matter of fact both works peacefully.

Comment: Ok, I checked your error, can you please update your code your now using too?

Comment: As it should be `../css/style.css` for the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

your html markup is invalid:

try https://validator.nu/ and you will find (among others)

```
Error: Bad value CSS\style.css for attribute href on 
element link: Backslash ("\") used as path segment delimiter.

At line 20
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style.css" >

---

Error: Bad value ../Image\unsplash.jpg for attribute src on 
element img: Backslash ("\") used as path segment delimiter.

At line 84
          <img src="../Image\unsplash.jpg"  alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">↩  

---

Error: Duplicate attribute class.

At line 124

ass="row" class="mybanner" sty
```